# Rails mongoid insert_many and associate with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm inserting many records into a rails mongoid ds as such:

```
products = [{id: "123"},{id: "345"}]
products.each do |product|
    product['product_id'] = product.delete 'id'
end
@store = current_user.store
# Clear the existing collection
@store.products.destroy_all
@store.products.collection.insert_many(products)
```

This works beautifully, however, the records entered into `Owner` are not associated with the `Owner`.
Examining a product, I can see that the field `owner_id` is nil.

I see that https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/Mongo%2FCollection:insert_many has the `options` hash. Is there a way to associate the records entered into the `Owner` when inserting them via the options. Would you do it before somehow? How do I associate each `product` entered into the `Owner` with the `Owner`?

Comment: What is `Owner` ?

Comment: @OlegP Owner is just a model. Owner has_many :products. - I updated my question to make it clearer and now using a store model instead. Have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a driver-level operation:

```
@store.products.collection.insert_many(products)
```

The driver only inserts the data you tell it to insert, i.e. only the keys/values in `products`. The driver does not have any knowledge of Mongoid associations or any other Mongoid features.

To associate products with their store, set `store_id` on each product accordingly:

```
products = [{id: "123", store_id: 1},{id: "345", store_id: 2}]
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I would edit your answer with 
```products.each do |product|
    product['product_id'] = product.delete 'id'
    product['store_id'] = current_user.store.id
end```
Since current_user.id will enter a BSON object into the store product vs a simple string ID